# $\mathfrak{ap\subsetneq a}$ , with $\mathfrak{a,p}$ ideals

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, domain-theory

> Let be $D$ a domain, $\mathfrak{a,b,p}\subsetneq D$ ideals with $\mathfrak{ab}=\lambda D\, , \lambda\in D\setminus\{0\}$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ prime **maximal**.

Show that $\mathfrak{ap\subsetneq a}$

Is easy to show $\mathfrak{ap\subset a}$ but I can't get $\mathfrak{ap\neq a}$

**EDIT** 
Forget write $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal.

[image: here comes the question]

Comment: Could you tell us where you found this problem, to give a bit more of context?

Comment: @A.P.  I'm in curse of algebraic number theory and our teacher gives us some theory for factorization of ideals and want to see class group of a domain. He tell us that he's making an experiment with our curse and he knows all results in our curse are true because we work in dedekind domains. This is not par of algebraic number theory yet, but usually we work with $\mathbb{Z}[w_d]$ as a domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** *I dropped the hypothesis that $D$ has a unity, but the following argument still assumes $D$ commutative (and doesn't use the hypothesis that $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime).*

If you multiply both sides by $\mathfrak{b}$ we see that it is enough to prove
$$
\lambda \mathfrak{p} \subsetneq \lambda D.
$$
Now, since $\mathfrak{p} \subsetneq D$ we can find some $d \in D \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ and since $\mathfrak{p}$ is an ideal (so $0 \in \mathfrak{p}$) we know that $d \neq 0$.
Then suppose that $\lambda D = \lambda \mathfrak{p}$. In particular, we can find a $p \in \mathfrak{p}$ such that
$$
\lambda d = \lambda p.
$$
Since $D$ is a domain we can cancel out $\lambda$ obtaining
$$
d = p \in \mathfrak{p}
$$
which is absurd because we explicitly chose $d \notin \mathfrak{p}$.

Comment: How do you use the fact that $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: Now the solution sufficient for me